# my submit buttons and select button shift all the words on that page to the left

Tags: html, css

As you can see in picture 1, my "rights reserved" is centered. But in picture 2, the words are shifted to the left.

1. [image]
2. [image]

Here's my HTML code for picture 1:

```html
<form action="Chapter 1.html" data-inline="true" style="float:right"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Next >">
  </form>
  </style>

  <div align="right">
    <select id="change" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
      <option value="Introduction.html">1. Introduction</option>
      <option value="Chapter 1.html">2. Chapter 1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

And my code for picture 2:

```html
  <form action="Chapter 2.html" data-inline="true" style="float:right"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Next >">
  </form>
  </style>

  <select id="change" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" style="float:right">
    <option value="Introduction.html">1. Introduction</option>
    <option value="Chapter 1.html">2. Chapter 1</option>
  </select>

  <form action="Introduction.html" style="float:right"> 
    <input type="submit" value="< Prev" id="previous">
  </form>
  </style>
```

My css code for both pictures:

```css
input[type=submit] {
    width: 5em;  height: 2em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    background: webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #ddd);
    background: linear-gradient(#fff, #ddd);
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background: #ddd;
}
#previous {
    width: 5em; height 2em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

#change{
    width: 9em; height: 2em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

As requested, here's my rights reserved code, html code is the 1st while the 2nd is the jScript code and the 3rd is the css code:

```
<footer id="foot01"></footer>
```

```js
document.getElementById("foot01").innerHTML =
"<p><center>&copy;  "+ new Date().getFullYear() + " Richard. All rights reserved.</center></p>";
```

```css
footer#foot01 {
    color: #000;
    align:center;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? :/

Comment: Please post the HTML and CSS code you are using in "rights reserved" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are floating `forms` and `select` items to `right`. Then you need to apply a `clear` to the `footer`:

```
footer#foot01 {
    clear: right;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/b8bnn4t3/2/)

Note: Also you have anothers errors, like `</style>` tags in HTML and `align:center;` that should be `text-align: center;`.

Comment: thank you! it worked! I would like to ask a question, what does "clear:right" mean?

Comment: Take a look at [this article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clear/).